# Company bankruptcy filings: updated daily, optionally historical

Tags: finance

I'm looking for data on bankruptcy filings. Not the total number, but specific companies and when they filed for bankruptcy. Historical data would be nice, but I'm most interested in up-to-date info. I know of [PACER](https://www.pacer.gov/), but that's difficult to use with scrapers or Google's [ImportHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) function.

Comment: Which jurisdictions are you interested in?

Comment: Anything I can get. All US BK courts being the most important.